# How to send base64 string as image in html body template in Node.js using nodemailer

Tags: node.js, base64, node-modules, nodemailer

I have nodejs request which need to embed the image base 64 string in the email html template body using nodemailer

as per the documentation
https://nodemailer.com/message/embedded-images/#example

```
let message = {
    html: 'Embedded image: <img src="cid:unique@nodemailer.com" alt="Red dot"/>',
    attachments: [{
        filename: 'image.png',
         content:'data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==',
        cid: 'unique@nodemailer.com' //same cid value as in the html img src
    }]
}
```

I tried sending the base64 attachment to nodemailer and htmlbody with image tag and it's cid,

but it shows broken image after receiving mail
[Image base64 string using cid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zprsd.png)
but if i tried same with the, image URL then its that image showing properly in received mail

```
let message = {
    html: 'Embedded image: <img src="cid:unique@nodemailer.com" alt="Red dot"/>',
    attachments: [{
        filename: 'image.png',
        href:  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/57/Cumulus_Clouds_over_Yellow_Prairie2.jpg",
        cid: 'unique@nodemailer.com' //same cid value as in the html img src
    }]
}
```

[Image href url with CID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaKwz.png)

Is there any workaround to handle same or any other syntactical changes needed to display base64 string?

Comment: Able to send the mail with base64 embedded image in Html template 

Inside attachments just need to **send** the base64 **in path variable instead of content**
```
 "attachments":  [{
        "filename": "image.png",
         "path":"data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==",
        "cid": "unique@nodemailer.com"
    }]
```